# whole word search with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Just started wtih elasticsearch. And stuck with first question:

I have following strings in my es index:

"favourites",
"favourites\a1"

If I try to search only first with

```
'query' => [
    'match' => [
        'name' => 'favourites'
    ]
],
```

or

```
'filtered' => [
    'filter' => [
        'term' => [
            'name' => 'favourites'
        ],
    ]
]
```

It matchs both. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`"index": "not_analyzed"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) in your mapping, and a [term filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html) in your query (or a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)).

For example, I can set up a simple index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

add a couple of docs

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name": "favourites"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name": "favourites\\a1"}
```

then this query will return only the first document:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "name": {
            "value": "favourites"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 45,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.30685282,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
               "name": "favourites"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used for a quick test:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/accb3e9aedc43144a30bb96fd483115427c6c441

Comment: Thx, very useful! But what if I need to keep abilty to make word-parts searching?
For instance I need to to search either "favourites" and "favourites\a1" with key word "favourites".
After setting "not_analyzed" it will be impossible, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you use `not_analyzed` the only terms will be the exact text. On the other hand, the standard analyzer will split tokens on non-alphanumeric characters like '\'. So you'll probably want to set up your own custom analyzer.